# Electron JS vs CRX approach

Tags: reactjs, electron, chromium, crx

We have developed one application in React JS. The application release package size is around 15MB (This is including minification and compression)

The same application when I build it to a CRX file the total size comes to 3 MB.

whereas when I build the application with electron js and generate an ASAR file the file size remains 15 MB.

How CRX file and ASAR file have this much difference in size?

Note :

I tried a few methods to compress the ASAR file size. whatever I see in the ASAR file after extraction is project files only.